# Can a school look through your messages on a personal account if you logged in on your school computer?

Tags: encryption

Is it legal for a public school to scroll through your texts on a personal account of yours if it was on your school computer?

Comment: As a legal question, this is not on topic here. You can try over at law.stackexchange.com, though please search first to see if your question is already answered.

Comment: Every country could have different laws.
It would be certainly illegal in the EU, but I think it is illegal pretty much everywhere nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, anyone with administrator privileges can log your keystrokes and duplicate your username and password. They could also copy browser cookies or other data to continue your session.

This is one reason why many security professionals discourage accessing personal or company data on public terminals.

Whether it is legal depends on a number of details.

In the US, if there is a warning or a user agreement that indicates monitoring may occur, it is usually permissible to *observe* anything that occurs on the machine. Organizations that are highly secure (or paranoid) can install applications like ObserveIT with screenshot capability.

Poking around and stealing credentials isn't usually allowed, however---unless there is justification for an investigation. Schools in the US have complicated rights and responsibilities when it comes to student safety and privacy, so it is best to have a lawyer review the details if the issue is serious.